# R Command polr: response must have 3 or more levels

Tags: r

I am trying to code an ordinal logistic regression using R, but I keep getting this error which says: response must have 3 or more levels.

My independent and dependent variable are ordered factors and only have (O and 1):

```
dataset$defense <- factor(dataset$defense, levels=c(1,0),
                     , ordered = FALSE)


dataset$pol_violence <- factor(
  dataset$pol_violence, levels=c(1,0),
                          , ordered = TRUE)
```

and whenever I try to run the regression using this code:

```
m <- polr(defense ~ pol_violence, data = dataset, Hess=TRUE)
```

I get the error message: response must have 3 or more levels

What should I do?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. But you are trying to do a proportional log odds model with a response that only has two levels (0/1)? That seems like an unusual choice and hence the function is confused.

Comment: For some reason the website is not letting me add a picture to my post. But my dependent and independent variables are categorical and only have two levels. if proportional log odds model is not the appropriate model then what do you suggest I use instead?

Comment: ... logistic regression

Comment: Why `polr` ?  While it is true you can technically order a binary or dichotomous outcome (0.1) with a correction to your code which should be `ordered = TRUE` you don't really need `polr` since you only have a single outcome and single predictor https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/factors.html

Comment: Which regression command do you suggest i use instead of polr? I intend on also including control variables

Comment: `m <- glm(defense ~ pol_violence, data = dataset, family=binomial)`

Comment: Take a look at https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/

Comment: so yes, glm makes more sense I suppose? does that make more sense to you guys as well? thank you so much!